# SQL - can search performance depend on amount of columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have something like the following table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(  
    id serial NOT NULL
    search_col int4 NULL,
    a1 varchar NULL,
    a2 varchar NULL,
    ...
    a50 varchar NULL,

    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX search_col_idx ON mytable USING btree (search_col);
```

This table has approximately 5 million rows and it takes about 15 seconds to perform a search operation like

```
select * 
from mytable 
where search_col = 83310
```

It is crucial for me to increase performance, but even clustering the table after `search_col` did not bring a major benefit.

However, I tried the following:

```
create table test as (select id, search_col, a1 from mytable);
```

A search on this table, having the same amount of rows as the original one, takes approximately 0.2 seconds. Why that and how can I use this for what I need?

---

```
Index Scan using search_col_idx on mytable  (cost=0.43..2713.83 rows=10994 width=32802) (actual time=0.021..13.015 rows=12018 loops=1)
```

```
Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..95729.46 rows=12347 width=19) (actual time=0.246..519.501 rows=12018 loops=1)
```

---

The result of DBeaver's Execution Plan

```
|Knotentyp|Entität|Kosten|Reihen|Zeit|Bedingung|
|Index Scan|mytable|0.43 - 3712.86|12018|13.141|(search_col = 83310)|
```

---

Execution Plan from psql:

```
 Index Scan using mytable_search_col_idx on mytable  (cost=0.43..3712.86 rows=15053 width=32032) (actual time=0.015..13.889 rows=12018 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (search_col = 83310)
 Planning time: 0.640 ms
 Execution time: 23.910 ms
(4 rows)
```

Comment: If possible, could you add an Explain and Analyze for your two seperate queries, it would provide more context on what your SQL is doing.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Copy the result as text, then paste the text and put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: thats what I did

Comment: That's not a complete execution plan.

Comment: I don't get a query plan when I execute `explain analyze select * from mytable where search_col = 83310`. I use DBeaver (just in case that makes a difference).

Comment: `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`  just adds a cell saying `Buffers: shared hit=1143`

Comment: I'm not familiar with DBeaver, but you could also use psql on the command line to get a proper query plan without the client (DBeaver in your case) doing weird stuff with the result

Comment: The slowest thing I see here is one half of a second.

Comment: It looks like you have fifty text columns in each row of that table. And your `SELECT *` query fetches them all, serializes them, and pushes them through the network from your pg server to your client program.  Do you always use all the columns in the result? If not, maybe you should try enumerating the columns you need. `SELECT a3, a11, a25` for example. Fifty columns is a lot. It might even be denormalized if many of them are null in any given row. If performance is crucial, consider restructuring this.

Answer (score 2):

One way that the columns would impact the timing would be if the columns were large.  Really large.

In most cases, a row resides on a single data page.  The index points to the page and the size of the row has little impact on the timing, because the timing is dominated by searching the index and fetching the row.

However, if the columns are really large, then that can require reading many more bytes from disk, which takes more time.

That said, another possibility is that the statistics are out-of-date and the index isn't being used on the first query.